# Eclipse Dart installing gets conflicting dependency

Tags: eclipse, dart

Eclipse Marketplace can't install Dart due to dependency conflict:

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Dartboard - Dart language support for Eclipse 0.1.0.202001060850 (org.eclipse.dartboard.feature.feature.group 0.1.0.202001060850)
  Software currently installed: M2E - POM Editor using LemMinX language server (includes Incubating components) 2.0.4.20230520-0934 (org.eclipse.m2e.lemminx.feature.feature.group 2.0.4.20230520-0934)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Language Server Protocol client for Eclipse IDE (Incubation) 0.16.1.202305241229 (org.eclipse.lsp4e 0.16.1.202305241229)
    Language Server Protocol client for Eclipse IDE (Incubation) 0.13.0.201912071343 (org.eclipse.lsp4e 0.13.0.201912071343)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Dartboard - Dart language support for Eclipse 0.1.0.202001060850 (org.eclipse.dartboard.feature.feature.group 0.1.0.202001060850)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.lsp4e [0.13.0.201912071343,0.13.0.201912071343]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: M2E Maven POM File Editor using Wild Web Developer, LemMinX and Maven LS extension (requires Incubating components) 2.0.3.20230520-0934 (org.eclipse.m2e.editor.lemminx 2.0.3.20230520-0934)
    To: osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.lsp4e 0.13.7
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: M2E - POM Editor using LemMinX language server (includes Incubating components) 2.0.4.20230520-0934 (org.eclipse.m2e.lemminx.feature.feature.group 2.0.4.20230520-0934)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.m2e.editor.lemminx [2.0.3.20230520-0934,2.0.3.20230520-0934]
```

installed software in eclipse:

- eclipse marketplace 1.10.0
- eclipse web developer tools 3.0
- buildship grade integration 3.0
- pydev - python ide for eclipse 10.2.0
- qwickie 1.2.0

How do I remove the conflict?

I tried getting rid of all the installed software, but it did not help.

Comment: The error message says that the Dart plugin you want to install (please link to the Marketplace entry) is bound to the specific version 0.13.0.201912071343 (`201912071343` means it is from December 7, 2019) of the [LSP4E](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/technology.lsp4e) plugin instead of the version range 0.13.0 .. 1.0.0. The problem is that you have LSP4E in a never version for m2e (Maven support) and Wild Web Developer and that LSP4E is a singletone excluding the presence of different versions of it. Please report this to the Dart plugin vendor. As workaround use an older Eclipse.

Comment: do you happen to know which version of Eclipse would be the right one to use?

Comment: If you mean this [Dart Plugin for Eclipse](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/dart-plugin-eclipse-0), you can [click on the download icon bellow the _Install_ button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgWvB.png) and it says Eclipse 2019-12 which is 14 releases behind.

Comment: thanks... not sure I want to move back that far in the release cycle.....

Comment: You can try https://github.com/dart4e/dart4e instead of DartBoard